# Unicode-Ascii mixed string in python

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a string that is stored in DB as:

```
FB (\u30a8\u30a2\u30eb\u30fc)
```

when I load this row from python code, I am unable to format it correctly.

```
# x = load that string
print x # returns u'FB (\\u30a8\\u30a2\\u30eb\\u30fc)'
```

Notice two "\" This messes up the unicode chars on frontend
Instead of showing the foreign chars, html shows it as \u30a8\u30a2\u30eb\u30fc

However, if I load append some characters to convert it into a json format and load the json, I get the expected result.

```
s = '{"a": "%s"}'%x
json.loads(s)['a']
#prints u'FB (\u30a8\u30a2\u30eb\u30fc)'
```

Notice the difference between this result (which shows up correctly on frontend) and directly printing x (which has extra ).
So though this hacky solution works, I want a cleaner solution.
I played around a lot with x.encode('utf-8') etc, but none has worked yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have control over the database? It seems like the real problem is storing it like that in the first place. Also, Unicode is a superset of ASCII and there's no such thing as "mixed" encodings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have a Unicode string, encode it back to ASCII and decode it with the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
>>> s = u'FB (\\u30a8\\u30a2\\u30eb\\u30fc)'
>>> s
u'FB (\\u30a8\\u30a2\\u30eb\\u30fc)'
>>> print s
FB (\u30a8\u30a2\u30eb\u30fc)
>>> s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')
u'FB (\u30a8\u30a2\u30eb\u30fc)'
>>> print s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')
FB (エアルー)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_string = '\u30a8\u30a2\u30eb\u30fc'
string = ''.join([unichr(int(r, 16)) for r in raw_string.split('\\u') if r])
print(string)
```

A way to solve this, expecting a better answer.